# Fire only one event after deleting multiple DataTable rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, rowdeleting

I have a `DataTable` with many rows, and the `DataTable` is bound to a `DataGrid`. After deleting one or more rows via the `DataGrid`, I need to run specific, quite complex checks on the remaning rows.

I subscribe to the `RowDeleted` event, and call the checking method from there. My problem is, when deleting multiple rows via the `DataGrid`, the `RowDeleted` event is fired for every single row, calling the checking method every time. As the checking method checks all the remaining rows and all their columns, it is a big slowdown for my application, also very redundant. It would be enough to run it once all the selected rows are deleted.

Is there a way to fire **only one** event after deleting any number of rows?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because if you are using WPF, perhaps you should rely on WPF-type features. In any case, I don't think that there are too many approaches more efficient than the proposed one (global variable to condition how a given event is called).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with the help of a timer. Declare a global timer and set its properties:

```
System.Timers.Timer _delayTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
_delayTimer.Elapsed += new EventHandler(_delayTimer_Elapsed);

 void _delayTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     _delayTimer.Stop();
     Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(UpdateMethodName)); 
     //or - with passing arguments:
     Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string>(UpdateMethodName), new object[]{"argument"});
 }
```

Now in your RowDeleted-Event, you do this:

```
_delayTimer.Stop();
_delayTimer.Start();
```

Because the timer gets restarted in the RowDeleted-event over and over again, your update logic will only get called after the last handler is fired.

Comment: I'm using WPF, not WinForms, but your idea is interesting. Can you transform it to WPF?

Comment: This is WPF, it just uses the Forms.Timer object. Editted my code, not it uses a Timers.Timer object. ;)

Comment: I just tried it. The "update logic" uses the GUI. The result: `InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.` --> OK, this one solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267956/answered-update-mainwindow-on-timer-elapsed-event

Comment: Use the Dispatcher.Invoke method to call your update logic from a different thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx

Comment: Or use a `DispatcherTimer`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add `Checkbox` column to your datagridview and provide a `delete button`and let the users to delete single or multiple rows only by selecting relevant checkbox on each  row.

And add your logic which checkes remaing rows within delete command of the button. This will make sure that your logic will run once per delete regardless numbers of rows being deleted.

Comment: Sorry, but this solution with modifying the `DataGrid` with additional checkboxes and a delete button is against the requirements. Also, this is about WPF `DataGrid`, not the WinForms `DataGridView`. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to handle the `Delete logic in your ViewModel` like:

1. Handle the `'Delete' keydown event and bind it to the Command on viewmodel` using interactivity.
2. Bind the `SelectedItems` property of `DataGrid` to the `CommandParameter` for the Delete Command.
3. In the `DeleteCommand handler, remove the items from the DataGrid's ItemsSource.`
4. After deleting the items, you can run your checks

Comment: The `DataGrid` only has a `SelectedItem` property. Can you please give an example, how to bind that to my `DataTable`?

Comment: it does have it.. but as it a readonly property, binding to it is not straight forward, so you can send them as the command parameter..updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear enough without a working example code.