# C# wpf chat client thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding, chat

I have this code:

```
public Model.Seznam<Model.Zprava> Seznam
    {
        get
        {
            return this.seznam;
        }
        set
        {
            this.seznam = value;
            this.ZmenaVlastnosti("Seznam");//ChangeProperty
        }
    }
```

It's for this listbox

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="328" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="285" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Seznam}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource VyberSablony}" />
```

The problem is, that I am using Seznam in main thread (adding messages, which I'Ve sent - `Seznam.Add(..)`) and I need to add received messages from other thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839296/using-the-c-sharp-dispatcher

Comment: I've tried this:
`Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => Seznam.Add(new Model.Zprava(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "Server: " + Zprava, Model.Od.Server))));`
And I get "object reference not set to an instance".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
public static void UiInvoke(Action a)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(a);
        }
```

And how to call it:

```
UiInvoke(() => { Seznam.Add(new Model.Zprava(DateTime.Now.ToString(), data, Model.Od.Server)); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dispatcher:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)( () => ZmenaVlastnosti("Seznam") ));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824(v=vs.110).aspx